# data annotations outside ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I want to use `RegularExpressionAttribute` on a property of some object, but the object will be used outside ASP .NET. I also want to customize the error message associated with `RegularExpressionAttribute`. For example, I want to the error message to be something like this:

The 'value' you have entered does not match the required pattern.

Is there a way to specify the 'value' part of the error message? It looks like I could use `IValidatable` interface, but maybe there is an easy way that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and use the same annotations. Not sure how you would wire up the validation though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

The RegularExpressionAttribute inherits from ValidationAttribute. This has attributes like ErrorMessage, ErrorMessageResourceName and ErrorMessageResourceType.

The values can be applied directly where you apply them:

```
[RegularExpressionAttribute(Pattern="xxx", ErrorMessage = "My custom message.")]
```

When you would want to mixin the value as part of the response you could create your own attribute by inheriting from the standard attribute. Here's a sample:

```
public class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    private string _value;  

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {   
        return string.Format("Value {0} is not valid.", value);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        _value = value.ToString();
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but how do I specify the 'value' part? I want whatever the property has as a value be part of the error message. For example, if property contains '123', I want '123' be part of the error message.

Comment: Ok, I did not catch that part of the requirement on first glance. Now things get a bit more involved. I did such a thing once with 'localized' attributes by creating a custom class inheriting from the given attribute and then overriding the FormatErrorMessage method.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but if I wanted to use other data annotation attribute, I would have to derive a class from every other attribute and override 'FormatErrorMessage' method. Also, it's possible that the error message may be different for the same attribute class when it's used with other object properties.

Comment: For derrived version of attributes I have no solution. ErrorMessage is a property of this attribute, so you have full control on the error message value.You could apply some creativity where the name value gets passed into the FormatErrorMessage. Since this value can manipulated by applying the DisplayName attribute as well. When you parameterize the error message, you could  return expressions string.format('{0} custom error message',name).